How to use azure cli to upload custon TLS certificates to Front Door
I need to maintaing custom TLS certificates up-to-date while using Azure Front Door with a scheduled bash script.
When doing it with application servers, it can be done in two steps in this (bash script example):
1. upload the certificate and get a thumbprint from it:

thumbprint=$(az webapp config ssl upload --subscription "$subscription" --resource-group "$resourceGroup" --name "$webApp" --certificate-file "$domain".pfx --certificate-password "$pfxPass" --query thumbprint --output tsv)

2. bind the certificate using the thumbprint:
az webapp config ssl bind --subscription "$subscription" --resource-group "$resourceGroup" --name "$webApp" --certificate-thumbprint "$thumbprint" --ssl-type SNI

The cli documenttation for Front Door does not indicate, in an way I could find, how to upload the custom certificates...
Is there a way to do it with an azure cli command?
if not, is there another alternative way to do it from a bash script? (azure's API maybe)
Using the Azure management UI should not be an option as the intention is to have this as n automated scheduled task

As it turns out the docs for front-door state that in order to upload custom TLS certificates we need to host them in key-vault and reference the key vault certificate from front-door.
So to resolve it I followed the instructions from the docs, and it worked:

Create the certificate* and upload it to key-vault
Create a system identity to front-door
Grant the front door identity read access to the certificate (read the docs for details)
selected the cerrtificate with "Latest version" from key-vault

After that the certificate can be uploaded to key-vault with the command caommand below, and front-door will always get the latest uploaded version:
az keyvault certificate import --vault-name "KEY_VAULT_NAME" -n "KEY_VAULT_CERTIFICATE_NAME" -f "PFX_FILE_PATH" --password "PFX_PASSWORD"

*The docs also state that:

Azure Front Door doesn't support certificates with elliptic curve cryptography algorithms.

As elliptic curve cryptography algorithms is the default type you might want to change the cerrtificate generation so it uses AES based algorithms.
